# Swap two sides of an = in a string

Tags: string, bash, sed

I have a string that looks like this:

```
755="Some String In Here"
```

I want to swap the two fields so it would become this:

```
"Some String In Here"=755
```

How do I do this using sed or some other command line tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how it can be done with `sed`:

```
$ echo '755="Some String In Here"' | sed 's/\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/\2=\1/'
"Some String In Here"=755
```

Note that this works even if the string on the right-hand side contains the `=` character:

```
$ echo '1="a==b"' | sed 's/\([^=]*\)=\(.*\)/\2=\1/'
"a==b"=1
```

Comment: What if line is some like `755="Some String In Here" 42="more data"`

Comment: @Jotne: TBH I don't see how that fits with the OP's requirement, and it's unclear what they would expect to happen anyway.

Comment: As far as we see there are only one `=` on every line, and only one group of data on every line, but we do not see all the data, so who knows.

Answer (score 2):

Through awk,

```
$ echo '755="Some String In Here"' | awk -F= -v OFS="=" '{print $2,$1}'
"Some String In Here"=755
$ echo '755="Some String In Here"' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}{print $2,$1}'
"Some String In Here"=755
```

At the BEGIN block, we set the Field Separator and the output Field separator to `=` symbol. And finally we print the column 2 plus the Output field separator value `,` plus the column 1 value.

Comment: Can be shorten some to: `awk -F= -vOFS== '{print $2,$1}'`.  You do not need the `OFS` in the print, since you have already set it to `=`, use just the `,`

Comment: Note that this fails if the string on the right-hand side contains a `=`.

Comment: @NPE according to the question title, his input has only one `=` symbol.

Comment: @NPE That is true, same is `sed`.  We need to have all the input to make sure there are not other problems showing up.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: You might well be right, but I am not seeing that stated in the question.

Comment: @Jotne: That depends on the solution. Mine (below) does not have this limitation.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
$ echo 755=\"Some String In Here\" | sed -r 's/(.*)=(.*)/\2=\1/'
"Some String In Here"=755
```

Answer (score 1):

Pure Bash with regular expression:

```
string='755="Some String In Here"'

[[ $string =~ ^([^=]+)=(.*) ]] && printf '%s=%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

or with parameter expansions (this also works in POSIX shells):

```
printf '%s=%s\n' "${string#*=}" "${string%%=*}"
```

Will work fine if there are several equal signs:

```
$ var='a="b=c"'
$ [[ $var =~ ^([^=]+)=(.*) ]] && printf '%s=%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
"b=c"=a
$ printf '%s=%s\n' "${var#*=}" "${var%%=*}"
"b=c"=a
```